# Cannot change the headline font size using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I cant change the font size of my heading tags inside some div while I can change the color of it.

This code works when trying to change the color of headings:

```
var childDivs = document.getElementById('content').getElementsByTagName('h4');

for( var i=0; i<childDivs.length; i++ )
{
 var childDiv = childDivs[i];
 childDiv.style.color= "red"
}
```

while this one when trying to change its size does not work:

```
var childDivs = document.getElementById('content').getElementsByTagName('h4');

for( var i=0; i<childDivs.length; i++ )
{
 var childDiv = childDivs[i];
 childDiv.style.fontSize = "52px"
}
```

Any idea why I cant change the font size of h4? Thou it works with paragraphs.

Comment: show html please

Comment: Check the developer tools， the style of the one which size doesn't work

Comment: It is still work with your updated content

Comment: you can try this: var childDivs = document.querySelectorAll('#content h4');

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce, It still worked for setting font size.

May be you did not put script tag before closing body tag

You need check if before your #content has div with #content using, it will not work with second div with id=content.

```js
//var childDivs = document.querySelector('#content').querySelectorAll('h4');

var childDivs = document.querySelector('#content').getElementsByTagName('h4');
//alert(childDivs.length);
for( var i=0; i<childDivs.length; i++ )
{
 var childDiv = childDivs[i];
 childDiv.style.fontSize = "52px"
}
```

```html
<div class="col-sm-12 content text-left mt-2" id="content" style="font-size: 120%;"><p class="preamble mt-3" style="font-size: 120%; line-height: 100%;">Småspararna drabbas när bankerna skär ner på sin aktieanalys. – Det är illa om bara de stora institutionella placerarna har tillgång till professionell aktieanalys, säger Börsstiftelsens vd Sari Lounasmeri. </p><div class="html">Av tradition har bankerna hållit sig med aktieanalytiker, som bevakat bolag och branscher för att kunna ge placerarna råd om vilka aktier de ska köpa eller sälja. Den här servicen har bankerna gett gratis för att locka kunder till sin avgiftsbelagda aktieförmedling.</div><div class="html">Nu har digitaliseringen, ökad konkurrens och större prismedvetenhet bland kunderna pressat avgifterna för aktieförmedlingen så att bankens intäkter inte täcker utgifterna för högavlönade analytiker. Samtidigt påverkas branschen av EU:s Mifid 2-direktiv som förutsätter att kostnaden för aktieanalys inte får vara inbakad i förmedlingsavgifterna. Syftet är att rådgivningen ska vara så opartisk som möjligt och att provisioner inte ska få styra vilken rådgivning bankerna ger.</div><div class="html">OP och S-banken förde under hösten samarbetsförhandlingar vilket innebar en minskning av antalet analytiker. Också Nordea och Danske Bank har bantat sin service.</div><div class="html">För stora institutionella placerare är det här inget problem. De kan betala för aktieanalys eller hålla sig med egna analytiker. De som drabbas är småspararna. För dem minskar tillgången till professionell analys som stöd för placeringsbesluten.</div><div class="html">– Det är illa om vi får en situation där bara de stora institutionella placerarna har tillgång till professionell aktieanalys, säger Börsstiftelsens vd <b>Sari Lounasmeri</b>.</div><div class="html">– Det är möjligt att vi i framtiden får robotiserad analysteknik som gör det lätt för var och en att göra sina analyser, men vi är inte där ännu. Att manuellt göra bolagsanalyser är svårt och tidskrävande för många, säger Lounasmeri.</div><h4 class="headline">Ny affärsmodell</h4><div class="html">Svårigheten att få lönsamhet i aktieanalysen har resulterat i nya affärsmodeller, så kallad uppdragsanalys eller sponsrad aktieanalys, som går ut på att det bolag som är föremål för analysen själv betalar för den. Här har analysföretaget Inderes kommit längst, men enligt HS tillämpar också Evli modellen, liksom i viss mån Nordea och Danske Bank när det gäller små bolag som annars inte skulle få plats i bankernas normala bevakning.</div><div class="image"><img width="100%" src="https://doeho6k8shw5z.cloudfront.net/imengine/image.php?type=preview&amp;uuid=dde2a1cd-cc18-46f8-bb85-42ea3d5d669b" alt=""><p style="font-size: 120%; line-height: 100%;"><i>Flera banker har skurit ner på sin aktieanalys.</i> <strong>Lehtikuva/Jussi Nukari</strong></p></div><div class="html">Den här modellen har dock väckt frågor om analytikerns opartiskhet gentemot det företag som samtidigt är betalare. Ett exempel på vad modellen kan leda till fick vi härom veckan, när Inderes meddelade att man slutar bevaka Stockmann. Orsaken var att analysföretaget tänkte börja ta betalt av Stockmann för att analysera bolaget, men Stockmann ville inte betala.</div><h4 class="headline">"Bäst om användaren betalar"</h4><div class="html">Enligt Sari Lounasmeri skulle det mest logiska vara om den som använder informationen också betalar för den.</div><div class="html">– Men vi är inte vana att betala för ekonomisk rådgivning. För många småsparare är placeringsbeloppen ofta så små att oproportionerligt stora summor skulle gå enbart till analysen.</div><div class="html">Vd:n för Aktiespararnas Centralförbund <b>Tuomo Katajamäki</b> förutspår att också småspararna med tiden får vänja sig vid att betala för professionell aktieanalys.</div><div class="html">– Annars är risken att det man får gratis bara är vissa delar och att den publiceras senare till dem som inte betalar.</div><div class="html">På längre sikt ser Katajamäki en möjlighet att grunda olika pooler som gemensamt beställer analyser och sedan distribuerar dem till medlemmarna. Till exempel kunde Aktiespararna upprätthålla en sådan pool, säger han.</div><div class="html">– Preliminära planer finns, men inget konkret än så länge.</div><div class="html">När det gäller den sponsrade aktieanalysen ser Sari Lounasmeri ytterligare en risk: hur många analyser är bolagen beredda att bekosta? Risken finns att det uppstår en monopolsituation där ett enda analysföretag blir dominerande och mångfalden lider.</div><div class="html">– Det vore viktigt att det inte finns bara en sanning, utan att placerarna kan jämföra olika synpunkter och väga dem mot varandra.</div><br></div>
```

Comment: has to be comment not answer